# var from javascript cookie being ignored

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have made a time counter. The topic is to make it starting from the point it stopped after the last page visiting.
E.g., it was "00:02:21" and after reloading the page, it starts from this point, not from the very beginning.
I decided to use cookies for this aim.

**The idea is** to take the *time* var from the cookie and use it, then *time* is rewrited in the cookie:

The example (http://jsfiddle.net/JuxZr/):

```
function simple_timer(sec, block) {
document.cookie = 'window.time=sec; expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2091 20:47:11 UTC; path=/; ;domain=.nekamera.ru'

var day = Math.floor(time / 86400);
time = (time - day * 86400);

var hour = Math.floor(time / 3600);

time = (time - hour * 3600);

if ( hour < 10 ) hour = '0'+hour;
var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
time = (time - minutes * 60);
if ( minutes < 10 ) minutes = '0'+minutes;
var seconds = time;
if ( seconds < 10 ) seconds = '0'+seconds;
block.innerHTML =  day + ' days ' +  hour+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
sec--;
    if ( sec > 0 ) {
        setTimeout(function(){ simple_timer(sec, block); }, 1000);
    } else {
         simple_timer(15, block);}
       }

function start_countdown() {
    var block = document.getElementById('sample_countdown'); //restart the timer live
    simple_timer(15, block);
}


window.onload=start_countdown;
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.time=sec` in the line:

```
document.cookie = 'window.time=sec; expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2091 20:47:11 UTC; path=/; ;domain=.nekamera.ru'
```

is never actually interpreted by the parser, but only stored as a string. What you want to do is store the time in a string format, then parse that string into a variable in subsequent requests.

Set cookie:

```
document.cookie = 'time=' + sec + '; expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2091 20:47:11 UTC; path=/; ;domain=.nekamera.ru'
```

Read cookie:

```
// from w3schools
function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_value = null;
    } else {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1) {
            c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
}

var time = parseInt(getCookie('time'));
```